# CSS variables change transition

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-variables

It's possible to apply transition / animation to a CSS variable itself? instead of the CSS property? Something like:

```
.home {
  --foo: red;
  background: var(--foo);
  transition: --foo 200ms linear;
}

.home:hover {
  --foo: blue;
}
```

Comment: Not like that. The variable would have to be the *property* not the value...

Comment: It's really not clear what you are expecting to gain here.

Comment: Yes, but it should be `transition: var(--foo) 200ms linear;` .

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Even that won't work since the variable is a value not a property.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus this is same that ```transition: red 200ms linear``` this makes no sense

Comment: oups, you'r right , i only looked at the syntax @Paulie_D

Comment: I believe you may be after `transition: background 200ms linear`?

Comment: it's possible but only Chromium browser support this for now. Check the duplicate

Comment: @Paulie_D --foo is already a property. It's a *custom* property

Comment: But you can't use it like that. In the transition it's a value and you can't transition `red`

Comment: If `--foo` was `background` it might be different,

Comment: @Paulie_D you can: https://jsfiddle.net/bh7k6a30/2/ .. the only issue is that the browser won't recognize the type since a custom property is handled as a string by default so its transition will behave like display but if you register the property with a type it will have a transition. We are not transition the value red but the property --foo between two values

Comment: thanks, really it cannot animate/transition because the browser do not know what is the type of the value to animate. It seems that there is a feature (currently only work on chromium) that allows me to declare an property, allowing me to animate it.